# How to use clojure-lsp in Emacs?

Tags: clojure, development

I downloaded clojure-lsp (https://github.com/snoe/clojure-lsp) and tried to add it as a client in my init.el:

```
  (use-package lsp-mode
    :ensure t)
  (use-package lsp-ui
    :ensure t
    :config
    (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'lsp-ui-mode))
  (lsp-define-stdio-client
   lsp-clojure-mode
   "clojure"
   (lambda () default-directory)
   '("~/bin/clojure-lsp")
   )
```

However when I do `M-x lsp-mode` in a clojure file, I only get this error after a short while:

```
Error during redisplay: (eval (lsp-mode-line)) signaled (wrong-type-argument lsp--workspace nil)
```

How do I correctly add clojure-lsp to lsp-mode?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `lsp-mode` is currently being reworked. That means that the syntax for registering servers works different now:

```
(lsp-register-client
 (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection "pyls")
                  :major-modes '(python-mode)
                  :server-id 'pyls))
```

So you might need to check out the latest README on github for up to date information:

https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode

Answer (score 1):

There are now [instructions](https://github.com/snoe/clojure-lsp#emacs) for configuration with emacs lsp-mode. The following is taken from what's currently there. You will need to start by putting the `clojure-lsp` executable on your path.

```
(require 'lsp-mode)
(lsp-register-client
 (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection '("bash" "-c" "clojure-lsp"))
                  :major-modes '(clojure-mode clojurec-mode clojurescript-mode)
                  :server-id 'clojure-lsp))
(add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(clojure-mode . "clojure-mode"))
(setq lsp-enable-indentation nil)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'lsp)
(add-hook 'clojurec-mode-hook #'lsp)
(add-hook 'clojurescript-mode-hook #'lsp)
```